# how to customize order by in (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, menuitem

I have little doubt. I have my own plugin to show some buttons. I just show you some code that is working on it.

**This is my php function corde inside**

```
print_r($instance['page']); //Result is showing under
           $args = array(
                'post__in' => $instance['page'],
                'posts_per_page' => $instance['items'],
                'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                'orderby'=>'date',
                'order'=>'ASC',
                'post_type' => $this->options->post_types,
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
           );
      }
```

When I print_r($instance['page']); The array result is like this.

```
Array ( [0] => 985 [1] => 145 [2] => 823 [3] => 807 [4] => 4107 )
```

But, menu order is going like that.

1. 145
2. 807
3. 823
4. 985
5. 4107

This is a menu order. But Now I need to show it in my own way. How I do that? 
Like - >

1. 145
2. 807
3. 985
4. 823
5. 4107

Something like this order.  Can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it my own. Sometimes that `'sort_column' => 'menu_order'` is not working in WordPress. So, If you have this own doubt. use as like below code. after that point your pages order in edit page option.

**here is the code that I used**

```
$args = array(
                'post__in' => $instance['page'],
                'posts_per_page' => $instance['items'],
                //'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order', //For now can use menu order in Wordpress 
                'order'=> 'ASC',
                'post_type' => $this->options->post_types,
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
           );
```

I hope this will help for someone looking for.

Thanks to StackOverFlow for help seekers!